# program is crashing due to pointer

Tags: c

I am learning pointers in  C. I understand `int * p = &a` will assign the address of `a`. Instead of this way I chose to store the address in another variable and then assigned it to the pointer variable `p`. I was expecting that program will execute as it usually  works with the above mentioned statement however my code is crashing at the line `*p=20;`. I am not any getting idea what is going on here .Please help me to understand it.

```
#include<stdio.h>

 void main(){
   int a=10;
   int adr = &a;
   int *p=adr;
   *p=20;
   printf("%d",a);
}
```

Comment: You can't do it that way.  Simple as that.  You can't store a pointer in an int, for the same reason you can't store a guitar in a toothbrush case.  (Or even if you manage to cram it in somehow, the guitar probably won't be playable afterwards.)

Comment: Please look at the compiler warnings! It *might* appear to work with a 32-bit compiler, but it has **undefined behaviour**. It *definitely* won't work as a 64-bit compilation.

Comment: *"Instead of this way I chose to store the address in another variable."* ===>
This exactly is your problem. You can't store a pointer variable in an `int` variable.

Comment: @SteveSummit, Thanks for the comment. I agree with your point. But my program is crashing during writing to memory. If I could know the exact reason that would be great help.

Comment: The reason was already mentioned: You cannot reliably store an address in a `int` variable. To verify you could print the address and the content of `p` and compare: `printf("&a=%p; p=%p", (void*)&a, (void*)p);`

Comment: You moved a 64-bit value to a 32-bit variable and then to another 64-bit variable. You have lost 32 of its bits, which cannot be recovered.

Comment: @Haris, what if we can typecast it to pointer ?

Comment: @WeatherVane, Is there any way to avoid it while keeping the intent same ?

Comment: The proper way to store a pointer is in a pointer variable.  So the best way would be to declare `int *adr;`.  But I'm not sure what your intent is.  If you're bound and determined to store the pointer in a non-pointer variable, you'll do better with `uint64_t adr;` or `intptr_t adr;`.

Comment: Not me, but the code suggests that you are *guessing* the C syntax, and there is a non-conforming definition of `main`. You expected the code to run despite the compiler warnings.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I have understood it . I will keep these things in mind .

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but one reason might be that your question reads like this: "I know that the right way to do it is A.  But for no good reason I want to do it by wrong way B instead.  Why did it fail the way it did?"  At one level, it's not an interesting question.  It's like asking, "I removed the lugnuts holding the front wheels on my car, then went for a high-speed drive.  A wheel flew off and I crashed into a ditch.  Why did that happen?"  I know that's not the kind of question you intended to ask, but that's how it looks to those of us answering.

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks for your view. Since I am learning pointer,  and until and unless I play with it I cannot grasp it in a better way.Simply reading or learning about something is not enough for me to fully understand it, but through hands-on experience or experimentation, I can gain a deeper understanding. I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code most likely crashes because `int` is not the same size as an `int*` on your system. I added casts to show what's going on:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {  // make it `int main(void)` to be portable
    int a = 10;
    int adr = (int) &a;   // (1)
    int *p = (int*) adr;  // (2)
    *p = 20;              // (3)
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

1. The pointer to `a`, most likely a 64 bit value, is assigned to an `int` which is most likely a 32 bit variable, so 32 bits are lost.
2. The 32 bit `int` is assigned to an `int*` - the missing 32 bits do not magically reappear
3. You assign a value to an address that is with a high probability not valid.

- Compiled in 32 bit mode: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/asor67Tz6)
- Compiled in 64 bit mode: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/de5nfYc8r)

Another example:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 10;

    // the original pointer:
    printf("%018p\n", (void*)&a);

    // after loosing 32 bits:
    printf("%018p", (void*)((uintptr_t)&a & 0xFFFFFFFF));
}
```

Possible output:

```
0x00007fc8e3a00020
0x00000000e3a00020
```

As you can see here, the top part of the address, `0x00007fc8`, is gone - and converting `0x00000000e3a00020` back to a pointer and using it will most likely end in catastrophy.

Comment: `printf("%d  %d",&a,adr);` gives me the same result.Not sure where it is lost.Please bear with me.

Comment: @novice `%d` requires an `int`, `&a` is an `int*` so that `printf` has undefined behavior too. You need to be very thorough when using `printf` so that you don't provide the wrong type of argument for the conversion specifier you've used.

Comment: is there any way to visualize the difference ?

Comment: @novice What difference? The difference between defined and undefined behavior? Did you understand my explanation for what happened in your program?

Comment: At line //1, I have lost the 32 bits,  If i can see what I have lost  then I think I could understand in a better way .

Comment: Yes, something like this. But there are things mentioned in the code which is unknown to me ?

Comment: @novice Ok, but I don't know what things in the code that are unknown to you. If you need me to describe anything in more detail, you need to tell me what those things are.

Comment: Could you please let me know how 32 bits losts in your code because In my case It is due assigning 64 bit value to 32 bit variable ?

Comment: @novice My code just visualizes the difference like you asked for. It doesn't loose any actual bits. It _would_ loose bits if I had assigned `(void*)((uintptr_t)&a & 0xFFFFFFFF)` to an `int*` though. It has undefined behavior already there.

Comment: Hi,  what If I use long variable instead of int  as long is 64 bit.

Comment: @novice You shouldn't really assume anything about the integer type needed. There is a pair of `typedef`s especially created for storing pointer values in integer variables, so use one of those. They are `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`. On one platform `intptr_t` may be a `typedef` for `int`, on another it may be `long` and on yet another it may be `long long`. Use the `typedef` to get it right. As a sidenote: It's more common to store pointer values in `unsigned` integer types, so `uintptr_t` would be my suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an annotated version of your program.  Running it should help illustrate what's going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int a = 10;
   printf("&a = %p\n", &a);
   int adr = &a;
   printf("adr = %x\n", adr);
   int *p = adr;
   printf("p = %p\n", p);
   *p = 20;
   printf("%d", a);
}
```